Correction and explanation of "Sing like a singer"
What is the difference between the two following sentences?


가수처럼 노래해요
가수와 같이 노래해요


(Please correct the sentences if they're grammatically wrong).
According to Korean - A comprehensive Guide section 3.3.6.1. we have

처럼 is a one-shaped particle that operates in the same way as 'like' in English to say that something/someone is like (i.e. the same as or similar to) something/someone else.

To me therefore 1. translates as:

Sing like a singer

According to Korean - A comprehensive Guide section 3.2.6.1. we have

과/와 같이/마찬가지 makes a comparison between the two which may be quite metaphorical.

Therefore to me 2. means "sing like a singer".
Therefore the two, apart from different grammar constructions they're equivalent. Is it the case? Are the two equivalent? if not what is the difference?


가수와 같이 노래해요. (X)
가수같이 노래해요. (O)

"-같이" and "과/와 같이/마찬가지" are slightly different.
"-같이" is an equivalent of "-처럼" and they're more close to "as if". "가수같이 노래해요" and "가수처럼 노래해요" are the same. The only difference is that because "-같이" originates from the adjective "같다(same)", "가수같이 노래해요" can be transformed into like: "노래하는 게 가수 같아요"
You can understand "과/와 같이/마찬가지" as "just as". "-같이" or "-처럼" is usually used to make a simile, but "과/와 같이/마찬가지" more focuses on comparison. For example:

지난 번과 같이/마찬가지 이번 회담도 헛수고로 끝났다: Just as the previous one, this summit ended in vain


공부 사이사이에 휴식이 중요한 것과 같이/마찬가지로 게임도 오랫동안 하지 않도록 유의해야 한다: Just as it is important to rest between studies, you should also be careful not to play games for a long time


모두에게 잊혀진다는 것은 죽는 것과 같다/마찬가지다: Being forgotten by everyone is the same as dying

"-같이" or "-처럼" and "과/와 같이/마찬가지" are used differently in some ways:

"과/와 같이/마찬가지" can be located at the end of the sentence as in the examples, while "-같이" or "-처럼" cannot.

When "과/와 같이/마찬가지" is not at the end of the sentence, it can be replaced with "-같이" or "-처럼". For example, you can say "지난 번처럼 이번 회담도 헛수고로 끝났다". But in this case, "-같이" or "-처럼" is used for comparison rather than simile. When "-같이" or "-처럼" is used for simile (like "가수같이 노래해요"), it cannot be replaced with "과/와 같이/마찬가지".

"과/와 같이/마찬가지" is formal while the "-같이" or "-처럼" is not.


And just a few more notes:

"마찬가지" is almost always used with particles like "마찬가지로", "마찬가지다", and "마찬가지예요". Just using "마찬가지" itself isn't grammatically wrong but it sounds condescending so it is usually used in sayings.
When you say "가수와 같이 노래해요", most people will understand "-와" as "with" and "같이" as "together" and the phrase becomes "sing together with a singer"
"과/와 같이/마찬가지" is not in the Korean dictionary. It might help you understand when you take two words separately and translate "과/와" as "with" and translate "같이/마찬가지" as "match" or "correspond".

